# Бесконечная загрузка страницы в Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, pdo

Создаю проект на Yii2, где нужно вывести таблицу базу данных на страницу. Но обо всем по порядку. 
Создал БД **application** в phpmyadmin на openserver, с таблицей **patients** в ней. Заполняю, экспортирую - все нормально. Но в Yii, при попытке загрузить post/show (страница с будущей БД) либо вылетает *"Database Exception – yii\db\Exception could not find driver Caused by: PDOException could not find driver in C:\Users\BEST\basic\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Connection.php at line 705"* (в данном случае строка **extension=pdo_mysql** в php.ini закомменчена, что закономерно), либо, при раскомментировании **extension=pdo_mysql**, то post/show просто бесконечно перезагружается и ничего не происходит.
Что я мог сделать не так?
Вот мои исходники, задействованные для данной операции:

**\controllers\PostController.php**

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;
use Yii;
use app\models\TestForm;
use app\models\Patients;

class PostController extends AppController{
    
    public $layout = 'basic';
    
    public function beforeAction($action){
        if($action->id == 'index'){
            $this->enableCsrfValidation = false;
        };      
        return parent::beforeAction($action);
    }
    
    public function actionIndex()
    {
    if( Yii::$app->request->IsAjax ){
            debug(Yii::$app->request->post());      
            return 'test';
        }
            
        $model = new TestForm();
        if ( $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) ){
            if ( $model->validate() ){
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Данные приняты');
            }else{
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', 'Ошибка');
            }
        }
        
        $this->view->title = 'Добавить пациента';
        return $this->render('test', compact('model'));
    }
    
    public function actionShow()
    {       
        $this->view->title = 'одна страница!';
        
        $patients = Patients::find()->all();
        
        return $this->render('show', compact('Patients'));
    } 
}
```

**\views\post\show.php**

```
<?php $this->beginBlock('block1'); ?>
<h1>title</h1>
<?php $this->endBlock(); ?>

<h1>Show Action</h1>

<?php debug($patients) ?>

<?php 

$js = <<<JS
    $('#btn').on('click', function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?r=post/index',
        data: {test: '123'},
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(res){
                console.log(res);
            },
            error: function(){
                alert('Error!');
            }
        });
    });
JS;

$this->registerJs($js);

?>
```

**\models\Patients.php** (да, я знаю, что просто выведется таблица с кодом, но это мне для начала и надо)

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

class Patients extends ActiveRecord {
    
    public static function tableName(){
        return 'Patients';
    }

}
```

**\config\db.php**

```
<?php

return [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost:8080;dbname=application',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Убери из контроллера все, оставь только `actionShow()`, попробуй вывести на экран то, что находится в переменной `$patients` в контроллере. View-шаблон тоже можно пока не подключать. Поэтапно пробуй, тогда проще найти ошибку. И форматирование кода надо подтянуть, а то в коде самому дольше разбираться будет.